# Spring Security with Angular - OAuth 2.0 login REST style

Tags: angular, spring-security

My Angular application is deployed to *localhost:4200* and Spring application is in *localhost:8080*. I am trying to implement OAuth2 security in purely REST style so entirely @RestController. All examples I saw requires returning a view which is discouraged.

Below is the intended flow :

1)My Angular button hits the :
http://localhost:8080/OAuthTrial/api/oauth-login

2)It should redirect to the Google Auth screen(I am trying to make Google work so I can translate to our custom OAuth server)

3)User authenticates and it hits back the callback endpoint in the Spring application and gets the "code"

4)The Spring application exchanges the "code" for access token and the access token for a JWT which it should send back to the Angular application

5)All the API endpoints must be secured with the JWT, which will be requested by the Angular application with the received JWT. The Spring application verifies  the JWT with the Auth server.

I have trying to make this work through Spring Security filter chain settings but wasn't able to. All examples involve returning a view. I am trying to not do that.

So my requirements are :

1)How to configure this in Spring Security. I tried doing this manually(making HTTPS requests to Google Auth server) and I get all the responses as expected but making the variables be available globally, Authentication setting etc. I see I have to do that manually also. So I figured I would use the standard implementation.

2)When I tried changing the Http "Location" header in my "oauth-login" endpoint, I getting the following error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth 
(redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/GoogleOpenId/api/login') from origin 'http://localhost:4200' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Anyway to alleviate

3)Is this flow impossible. I am trying to avoid Implicit flow. And as I was informed Authorization Code with PKCE is not supported for SPA websites here.
So I trying to make this work with Authorization Code where my Spring application is the OAuth Client and also a Resource Server.

If the community could provide SecurityConfigs and any other configs and any relevant knowledge, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`oauth2Login` security is based on sessions (and requires CSRF protection). Only `oauth2ResourceServer` security is based on tokens and can be stateless.

As you figured out already, it is now recommended to used only "confidential" clients (with a secret, which requires it to run on the server), and not to configure single-page or mobile applications as "public" clients.

Actually, it is even safer to keep tokens on the server and to rely only on session (with CSRF protection) between front and back ends:

- session cookies can (and should) be hidden from Javascript code, access tokens can't
- sessions can be invalidated, access tokens can't

The best option is probably to use an OAuth2 BFF like spring-cloud-gateway configured as OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` and with the `TokenRelay` filter, in front of your REST API configured as resource server(s). **I wrote a [tutorial for that on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).**

Of course, you could also configure your API as a client with `oauth2Login` (and use only session based security), without the need for a separate BFF. But then OAuth2 would probably not be the best choice (you would bother fetch and store tokens that would never be used).

As a side note, Google will probably deliver only opaque tokens that you can't efficiently use as access tokens for your own resource servers. You should configure your own authorization server (Keycloak) with Google as identity provider and login your user on Keycloak ("Login with Google" button) to use only tokens issued by your authentication server.

Comment: My technical knowledge is very insufficient to understand this. But thank you for the reply. I'll try and understand it.